# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at util.js:68 at bootstrap.min.js:6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I've encountered an error while running my application. I'm seeing this error on my console when I run the application

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
        <body>
            <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
            <div class="sidenav">
                <div class="login-main-text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>User Name</label>
                                <input type="text"id="userid" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div> 
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-black" value="Login" onclick="NullValidator()" @*window.location='Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")*@ />
                            @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>*@
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Register</button>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a style="float:left">Forget Password ? </a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        </body>
</html>
```

I've tried searching for the `fn` here but I didn't use it in this page and also on other pages of the application. So I can't determine the cause of the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved my problem by adding this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This may work but make sure that you are using bundling and minification for styles and javascript files.
Follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification